# Argument #1 ($callback) must be of type Closure, array given

Tags: php, closures, router, lexical

U am running a driving school system on PHP/Apache and I am getting this error when I am trying to load the system.

Errors appear to be from routes.php and SimpleRouter.php. Here is the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError:
> Pecee\SimpleRouter\SimpleRouter::group(): Argument #1 ($callback) must
> be of type Closure, array given, called in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\driving\src\routes.php on line 17 and defined in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\driving\vendor\pecee\simple-router\src\Pecee\SimpleRouter\SimpleRouter.php:182
> Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\driving\src\routes.php(17):
> Pecee\SimpleRouter\SimpleRouter::group(Array, Object(Closure)) #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\driving\src\Application.php(94):
> require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\driving\index.php(11): Simcify\Application->route() #3
> {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\driving\vendor\pecee\simple-router\src\Pecee\SimpleRouter\SimpleRouter.php
> on line 182

***Code snippet for routes.php line 17:* **

```
Router::group(['prefix' => '/driving'], function()
 {    
      Router::group(array(
        'exceptionHandler' => Handler::class
    ), function()
     {
        Router::group(array(
            'middleware' => Simcify\Middleware\Authenticate::class
        )
```

*Code snippet for simpleRouter.php line 182:*

```
  public static function group(\Closure $callback, array $settings = [])
    {
        if (is_callable($callback) === false) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid callback provided. Only functions or methods supported');
        }
```

Please assist. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Which part of the error message are you confused about? An [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is clearly not a [Closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php). Did you write this code yourself, or are you just running a copy of someone else's application?

Comment: @ADyson yes i am running someone else's application, i am a begginer

Comment: Unless you've amended the code yourself and therefore caused this issue, then clearly it contains a serious bug, and presumably it was not tested properly by the author - so you should return it to the author with a bug report and request an updated version of the software. I can see what the cause of the bug is but it's unclear to us (or to me, at least) what the actual _intent_ was, and therefore I can't suggest exactly what to replace the incorrect code with.

Comment: okay thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me as someone has tampered with `SimpleRouter.php`. The functions signature is (and always has been) `public static function group(array $settings, Closure $callback): IGroupRoute` and not vice versa.

Since it is inside the `vendor` folder, I suppose it was installed via composer? Make a backup and then try `composer update` for starters. If this doesn't work, add your `composer.json` to your question.

This is the source repository: https://github.com/skipperbent/simple-php-router/tree/master

Comment: Cannot use array as default value for parameter $callback of type Closure

Comment: @manompofu Huh?

Comment: I am getting that error after updating the SimpleRouter.php function. I will add composer.json to the question

Comment: And the complete new error message as well, please. I might not be able to get back to you before tomorrow though.

Comment: yes but this new error happened after i interchanged the function signature:  **public static function group(array $settings, Closure $callback)**,

Comment: the original code was:  **public static function group(array $settings = [], \Closure $callback)**

Comment: You **must not** change anything inside the dependencies!